# Oauth2 and PKCE redirect url for mobile apps

Tags: flutter, keycloak

I am creating a mobile app and use `Spring boot, Keycloak and Fluter` for that.
And I am struggeling to figure out what/ how should I set the redirect url when I choose `public access type` and `open id` in Keycloak.

For a web app I understand that because I give the server url but how about a mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

Use URL which your app can claim on the device.
Random post about this topic: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uris-native-apps/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried some solutions such as adding  the following in android build gradel manifestPlaceholders = [
                'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.sda.sdx_user_portal://login-callback',
                'applicationName': 'com.sda.sdx_user_portal.main'
        ] but I get .ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sda.sdx_user_portal.main